# Jailbreak my work phone

Tags: mac, iphone, jailbreak

I just got an iPhone from my company. I have to access my work email on this iPhone 4. 
However, I can't use Grooveshark as my music service, since it only works on jailbroken iPhones.

How can I jailbreak my phone so that company's server is unaffected? Or would it possibly even be affected in the first place?

How do I un-jailbrake the phone later, so I can return it to my company later unaltered?

Comment: Is the only thing your company did to the phone is configure the mail app? Are you actually dealing with iOS5? iOS5 hasn't been released yet.

Comment: So did you do it? If so, how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

Backup with iTunes to restore later, but just go to http://www.jailbreakme.com from you're iPhone, slide to unlock, and wait

Comment: Sounds like a viable approach to me. Just be SURE to have your backup image/file from iTunes. You should backup the backup image/file.

Comment: a) Will the company's server know that I am using jail break version. This is required since the updates has lot of policy information. b) Can I can go back to the original version without anyone knowing. I am not concerned about emails data. Just making sure they are secured.

Comment: With my iPhone 3G I found installing iOS updates would simply ruin the jailbreak, but everything else would continue normally. I doubt they'd ever notice, but I guess never say never.

Comment: They won't know unless you tell them or you get infected